# Angular Build: more than 3000 .js files

Tags: angular, webpack, build, webpack-production

When I build my project with `ng build --configuration production`, I get more than 3000 files in my /dist folder. Roughtly 300 of them have the current time as the "Date modified":[image]

Interestingly, there is so many other files that do not even have 4 kb:
[image]

Furthermore, those files have an older "Last modified" date with them, which I do not understand either. I do not know if this is any help, but the contents of those files look something like this:
[image]

Having this many files has two big disadvantages:
-FTP upload(to deploy the app) takes ages
-the ngsw-service worker sometimes(no idea whats happening there either) downloads all of those files to the client which also just generates an unnessecary high amount of requests.

I know that I could cut the amount if files in half (es5/es2015), but this still leaves me with way too many files. My friend works on a huge project too, but they only have 300 files or so in total.